# Comparing angle measurements from two different techniques

Tags: measurement, agreement-statistics

I'm working on a research project wherein we have 50 subjects. We have 3 x-rays per patient that all show a slightly different view of the same anatomic region. I am trying to compare an angle measurement made by a computer software based on the three x-ray types.

I want to identify if there are any significant differences in the angle measured by each x-ray type.

My data looks like this:

```
Patient 1, Angle from XrayA, Angle from XrayB, Angle from XrayC
Patient 2, Angle from XrayA, Angle from XrayB, Angle from XrayC
```

I was hoping someone could explain to me which test to use and why.

Comment: What are the possible values of the angle? Could it be (e.g.) any angle from $0^\circ$ to $360^\circ$?

Comment: yes. most are in the 15-50 range though.

Comment: i was thinking of doing something like: subtract one measurement from the other to get the differences. then construct a confidence interval and see if it spans 0.   not really sure how to approach this logically though

Comment: But you are comparing three measurements, not two. For angles over a small range, analysis of variance is a simple place to start, although I worry what "most" means.

Comment: Shouldn't the analysis be done in some sort of pair/trio-wise fashion since there are three measurements for one patient?

Comment: Depending on what your aims are and perhaps partly on how your experiment is set up, you could either treat patients as fixed blocks (with patient as a blocking factor) or as random effects (in a mixed model). If your patients are thought of as randomly selected from some population, you'd likely choose the second.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the former. One patient's angle is in no way predictive of another patient's angle, but his angle should be similar to the one measured by other x-rays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To gain a better understanding of the data I'd consider drawing three pairwise Bland-Altman-Plots and/or three plots plotting eacht method's result against the mean of all three measurements. 
If I understand "any significant differences in the angle" correctly, that might be a job for Friedman's test.

Bernhard